# CNF – satisfy at most a fixed number of clauses

Tags: algorithms, np-hard, satisfiability, parameterized-complexity

I'm working on this task:

> Prove that the following problem can be solved in time $2^{k} \cdot \Vert \varphi \Vert^{\mathcal{O}(1)}$: given a boolean formula $\Vert \varphi \Vert$ in CNF, decide whether there exists an assignment that satisfies at most $k$ clauses of $\varphi$.

but with very little success so far. I've only figured out that if a variable $\alpha$ is part of more than $k$ clauses, then it has to be set to false. Similarly for $\neg \alpha$. If these two facts hold for the same variable, then we obtain that it's not possible to satisfy the problem's requirements. So, we can now assume that every variable is part of at most $k$ clauses. But I'm stuck here. Could you give me a hint?

Comment: Where did you encounter this task?  We require you to credit the original source of all text originally written by others: https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing

Comment: @D.W. it's one of the problems we were going to cover in our class, but we didn't have time for it. It's not my homework if that's what you're asking about

Comment: Great, I encourage you to credit the original author (e.g., your instructor or the author of the textbook you're getting it from), as required by our guidelines regarding copying of text written by others!

Comment: What would you do if there was a variable with only positive occurrences (or only negative occurrences)?